# How do I use jQuery to directly manipulate CKEditor content?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I would like to use jQuery to directly manipulate the content in a CKEditor instance. For example, let's say I want to add a button that will find all h1's in the editor content and prepend the heading text with "Title:". This is easy in normal page content with jQuery: something like `$('h1').prepend('Title: ')` should do it.

However, I cannot find any information in the CKEditor docs about how to perform this kind of manipulation on the content, even from within a plugin. The closest I've found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13360543) to a similar question that claims it's possible from within a plugin, but it doesn't actually answer the question of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify which document to use in jQuery `$()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364987/1485219). [`document`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-document) is a property of editor instance. Then you got to make sure it's done after [CKEditor iframe's DOM is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461206/how-to-retrieve-the-ckeditor-status-ready/18464877#18464877):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            var doc = this.document.$;

            $('p', doc ).prepend( '(!) ' );
        }
    }
} );
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/1u6stj0g/).